# Validation in Excel

Tags: excel

How to do data validation in excel?
for example i have data as "P/CST/454" in a cell than how to validate that cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create somewhere in your document, e.g. on a separate config sheet, a list with the allowed values. highlight this range and give it a name (Either type the name in the Name Box, or using on the menu Insert - Name - Define).

Then you have a List of your values that has a name.

Now highlight the cell that you want to have validated. Goto the menu "Data - Validation". In this screen choose from "Allow" the entry "List" and under "Source" enter "=NameOfMyList".

There we are, now only the values from your list can be entered in the cell.

Update:

- It is possible to avoid the Name and enter the Range of your list directly under "Source"
- You can enter your allowed values also directly under "Source" separated by commas. But I would do this only if the list is very short.

Comment: the values are already saved i only have to invoke it automatically i want the syntex to be used in that perticular cell

Comment: @Kalps, can you update your question with what you have at the moment and explain what you want to achieve? Do you want not to check against a fixed list, but something like a format check?

Comment: How to do data validation in excel? for example i have data as "P/CST/454" in a cell than how to validate that cell?

Comment: @Kalps, I explained that in my answer. Validation means that you check if the content of the cell is valid. And which values are valid is defined in the List. What does validation means to you? Why is "P/CST/454" valid? Because it is the correct string, or the format is correct Letter/3Letters/3Numbers or what is valid?